# Is there a way to find out what has happened to the back stack?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, back-stack

In my Android acticity, I use [`FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#addOnBackStackChangedListener(android.app.FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener)) to listen for changes to the fragment back stack.

`OnBackStackChangedListener` has just one method [`onBackStackChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener.html#onBackStackChanged()), but doesn't pass information about the change.

Is there a way to gather this information anyway?

Specifically, I want to know if the fragment I added earlier is removed by this back stack change.

Comment: you could put or remove something, or what kind of events are you interesting in?

Comment: Edited my question. I guess for my case, is could try `findFragmentById` to check if the fragment is still there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to use `FragmentManager.enableDebugLogging(true);` (You can put it in the onCreate of your `Application`). This debugging will allow you to not only see the various life cycle events of your fragments but you can also see information about updates to the backstack.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

        FragmentManager.enableDebugLogging(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to just manually retrieve information from the back stack using `popBackStack`; you can either pop the most recent state from the stack or search for a specific state by specifying the name or the ID.

So to answer your question, you could create a local copy of the back stack and then when `onBackStackChanged()` gets called then you can compare your saved copy of the back stack to the current back stack to see what changed.